# Case Conversion using REGEX

Tags: regex, vba, excel

Using Excel with REGEX in VBA and I am new at this.

I need to convert the contents of one capture group from all uppercase to titlecase via the strReplace command. I can't use the Excel PROPER function on the results from strReplace because it doesn't provide the desired results.

Sample cell contents are (not all cells are like this one which is why string pattern definition is more encompassing):

```
FDI850-4224 JIM SMITH 29 HP (21.6 kw)
```

My string pattern is:

```
strPattern = "^(\D{2,4}\d{0,4})-(\d{1,4}) (.*)\s(\d\d)( HP)\s\((\d\d.\d)\skw\)"
```

My replacement pattern is:

```
strReplace = "$1-$2 - Juniper $1 Part, $3, $4HP, $6KW"
```

The current results that are placed in the adjacent cell are:

```
FDI850-4224 - Juniper FDI850 Part, JIM SMITH, 29HP, 21.6KW
```

My desired results to be placed in the adjacent cell are:

```
FDI850-4224 - Juniper FDI850 Part, Jim Smith, 29HP, 21.6KW
```

Is there something I can use in the strReplace for capture group 3 (.*) to change it from all uppercase to titlecase?

Here is my VBA code:

```
Function tom_test(Myrange As Range) As String

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String

strPattern = "^(\D{2,4}\d{0,4})-(\d{1,4}) (.*)\s(\d\d)( HP) \((\d\d.\d\d)\skW\)"

If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = Myrange.Value
    strReplace = "$1-$2 - Juniper $1 Part, $3, $4HP, $6KW"
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        tom_test = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)

    Else
        tom_test = "No Bueno"
    End If
End If    
End Function
```

I tried a two step process of taking the results from the REGEX function and then using the Excel PROPER function on it, but it mucked up the results of the other capture group results:
Here is what happened after using PROPER on the results from strReplace:

```
Fdi850-4224 - Juniper Fdi850 Part, Jim Smith, 29Hp, 21.6Kw
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Just use Proper on Capturing group 3.  How to do that depends on your VBA code.

Comment: Thanks. I added the VBA code to my question.  I do not know how to use Proper on just capturing group 3.

Comment: I've posted some code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit
Function tom_test(Myrange As Range) As String

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String

Dim MC As MatchCollection

strPattern = "^(\D{2,4}\d{0,4})-(\d{1,4}) (.*)\s(\d\d)( HP)\s\((\d\d.\d)\skw\)"

If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = Myrange.Value
    strReplace = "$1-$2 - Juniper $1 Part, $3, $4HP, $6KW"
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        Set MC = regEx.Execute(strInput)

        strReplace = Replace(strReplace, "$3", StrConv(MC(0).SubMatches(2), vbProperCase))

        tom_test = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)

    Else
        tom_test = "No Bueno"
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! I ran it and it worked. I have so much to learn. Thanks for helping out.